# How to exclude part of nodes in Rvest? Filter

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am **scraping** the page: https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/allenyheder/politik/

And I need to take the titles but I need to exclude some of them

The code I have is:

```
    # Defining URL
url <- "https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/allenyheder/politik/"

  dr.html <- read_html(final_url)

  titles1 <- dr.html %>%
    html_nodes(".heading-small h3 a>:not(.dr-list:nth-child(2) h3 a)") %>%
    html_text()
```

I need what is in the node .heading-small h3 a, excluding what there is in the .dr-list:nth-child(2) h3 a.

My code is not working.

I am getting the message: Error in parse_simple_selector(stream) : Expected ')', got h3

Thanks

Comment: If I understood what you want, this worked for me: `url %>% html_nodes("h3") %>% html_text()`?

Comment: No. It doesn't. It's because I need to exclude part of what I am scraping. So I do not want this part .dr-list:nth-child(2) h3 a, but all the rest that is in the node .heading-small h3 a.

Comment: I see. Which information do you need to extract from this url? You can discard things latter with R.

Comment: i need to extract titles, urls and dates from the news. The thing is that a lot of data (8 years scrapping). And if I could have this done before doing the looping would save a lot of time, because there's almost 60% of trash if I don't exclude before.

Comment: I'm trying to give you the titles, time and urls as you mentioned before. However I'm not sure which part you want to remove. This `url %>% html_nodes(".heading-small h3 a") %>% html_attr('href') %>% tibble(links = .)` will return a `tibble` (`data.frame`) with the links of the titles. As I told you, is very easier to clean things in R once you have them loaded.